# ODBC connection failed to DB2 instance with PHP 5.3.6-13ubuntu3.6

Tags: php, odbc, db2, ibm-midrange

I have installed DB2 Express-C V9.7, unixODBC php5-odbc and iSerie-5.4.0-1.6  Drivers for Linux but when i try to connect to the DB2 server php return me this message :

```
[unixODBC][IBM][iSeries Access ODBC Driver]Communication link failure. comm rc=10061  -
CWBCO1049 - The iSeries server application is not started, SQL state 08004 in SQLConnect
```

I noticed with tcpdump that php try to connect on port  8741 instead of 50000.

netstat -anp tell me DB2 listen port 50000

This is my configuration file

/etc/odbcinst.ini :

```
[DB2]
Description     = ODBC for DB2
Driver          = /opt/ibm/iSeriesAccess/lib/libcwbodbc.so
Setup           = /opt/ibm/iSeriesAccess/lib/libcwbodbcs.so
FileUsage               = 1
Threading               = 2
DontDLClose             = 1
UsageCount              = 1
```

/etc/odbc.ini

```
[local_db2]
Driver = DB2
System = localhost
User = db2inst1
Password = MySecretPassword
Port = 50000
Database = dbname
Option = 1
```

And my PHP Script :

```php
$dsn = "local_db2";
$user = "db2inst1";
$passwd = "MySecretPassword";
$conn = odbc_connect($dsn,$user,$passwd );

echo "votre id de connexion est : $conn";

if ($conn <= 0) { 
 echo "\nErreur\n"; 
} 
  else { echo "\nSuccès\n"; 
}

odbc_close($conn);
```

---

Now i can connect to DB2 server. I have changed port of db2inst1 in /etc/services but server don't respond me.

My error message is (after a while):
[unixODBC][IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver]Communication link failure. comm rc=8405 - CWBCO1047 - The IBM i server application disconnected the connection, SQL state 08S01 in SQLConnect

Conclusion :

The first problem was the drivers for iSeries that was not the proper drivers for my configuration so i have installed the [DB2 ODBC CLI driver](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21418043) which include drivers for linux.

The second problem was the odbc configuration.

My working /etc/odbc.ini configuration :

```
[DBNAME]
Driver=DB2
```

My working /etc/odbcinst.ini configuration :

```
[ODBC]
Trace       = yes
Tracefile       = /tmp/odbc.log

[DB2]
Description     = DB2 Driver
Driver      = /opt/ibm/db2/V9.7/lib32/libdb2.so
FileUsage       = 1
DontDLClose     = 1
```

You can get more details about your odbc connection in /tmp/odbc.log.
I used too the isql program who test odbc connection.
This program was in unixodbc linux package.

Thanks for your informations

Nicolas.

Answer (score 3):

It's likely the database host server has not been started.  The database host server accepts TCP/IP connections to the database.

You can check if it is currently active with the command `WRKACTJOB SBSD(QSERVER) JOB(QZDASRVSD)`.

The command to start it is: `STRHOSTSVR SERVER(*DATABASE)`.

The default port is 8471.

Comment: i'm a newby with DB2, but i don't have wrkactjob and strhostsvr utilities on my system.
I thinks it's OS/400 commands but i run DB2 on my ubuntu Linux

Comment: If you are running DB2 on Linux why are you using the iSeries Access DB2 driver?  You should be using a standard DB2 driver such as [DB2 ODBC CLI driver](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21418043).  The iSeries driver is only for connection to DB2/400.

Comment: Please update your question with what was the actual problem, and how you fixed it.